# SharePoint 2010 GAC deployment doesn't update

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, gac

The following issue just crept up on me.  The steps mentioned below had worked just fine until about 2 days ago.

When I deploy a update to a solution (of web parts) to a SharePoint 2010 server I don't see the update.  The solution does get installed, but from what I can tell the installed web parts are over a month old (nothing new is installed).

I do the following steps through PowerShell:

```
retract the solution from the web app
remove the solution  
add the solution  
install the solution to the web app
```

I have tried restarting the Web App, restarting IIS and also restarting the server.  Nothing seems to work.

I notice that after I remove the solution it does get removed from the GAC.  After I add/install it the solution does reappears in the GAC.

Am I missing something?  Am I overlooking a step that I should be doing?  Something to try?

Comment: `from what I can tell the installed web parts are over a month old`. Okay, but how can you tell? Do you just load the page in a browser?

Comment: Load in browser, but also looking at the date from within the Site Settings > Galleries > Web Parts.  The last modified is over a month old, when I know that I was working on them within the past few days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never deactivated/reactivated the Feature.

After following the same steps I mentioned in my question I just deactivated, then reactivated, the Feature and everything started to working fine.

This is an easy thing to I can start to implement with my solution updates.  However, why did I never have to do this step before?

Comment: ¿Is it possible that the assembly is in memory? ¿Can you try without de/reactivating the feature rebooting the system?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should check your ULS log to see which version of your solution is running. If you see the old one, then you can be sure that your activated site feature is still bound to the old version. In this case you have to Inactivate the site feature indeed to loose that tie and then Activate to bind to the new one (it appears Activate always ties the site feature to the newest version of the solution).

Maybe you had not to do this earlier, because you did not change the version number of your solution, appearing as the same version in GAC on the server. In this case you had your site feature already pointing to the correct version of your solution, therefore didn't have to reset the feature.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably checked, but just in case. Make sure that the powershell script is not adding a month old package.

Comment: I have checked, and the timestamp on the WSP file does correspond with when the solution was built (in this case this morning, not a month ago).

Comment: Try renaming the .wsp file to .cab, you will then be able to open it and check what is inside. Also double check the powershell script so that it is deploying the wsp you expect.

Comment: Changed wsp to cab.  Contents are what I suspect they would be (the new stuff).  Will double check the script and get back...

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem in the web part code or the configuration? The configuration usually unghosts itself sooner or later and refuses to update from the solution - you can update the file in the gallery manually if anything has changed there. For most updates there won't be any changes because existing web parts won't get updates applied anyway - they will use new code but old configuration.

If the problem is the code itself, does the assembly appear to the system to be unchanged? All the hardcoded full name references in SharePoint config files mean that usually you are deploying a new assembly but with the same version numbers. This can mean that the system doesn't bother making the update. I have found it very useful to update AssemblyFileVersion (which does not affect binding) on every build and have a page in _layouts that displays the file versions of all the loaded assemblies so I know exactly what is running.